# Wix installer "Installed" condition fails

Tags: wix

I am building a Wix installer in debug mode.

Whenever run the same build of the installer twice, on the second run it will evaluate the "Installed" condition properly however if I rebuild the installer, then the condition fails.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Is the product code changing between builds?

Comment: I use the asterisk (*) so I believe so.

Answer (score 2):

The second build generates a new installer package with a different product code. When you run that specific installer for the first time, it is not `Installed`. Perhaps the property `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` is what you are looking for.